# TO call ant command from shell script

Tags: shell, ant

I am working on a requirement to automate DataPower using ant commands.
I have store the ant commands in .sh file and started calling .sh file but its throwing error like " does not exist in the project "deploy". I have deploy.ant.xml with project name deploy and have many targets assigned in it.

When I trying to execute the ant command directly it is working fine.
Sample command:

```
ant -f deploy.ant.xml -Ddevice=devicename -Ddomain=default -Duid=username check-access
```

Can someone help me, please?